# Selenium webdriver is showing NoSuchElementException even when element is already present on the webpage

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am using `Selenium` with `Python` for Automation of a website for my organisation. I am using Mozilla FireFox Web Browser for this purpose. Firefox version is 72.0.1 (64 bit).

**I have already read all answers similar to my problem available in stack overflow but not able to get solution of my problem**

I am fetching some data from webpage in my Python program. My Program is able to fetch data related to maximum required fields from that webpage but not able to fetch data of a particular field. [image: This is the image of of that field]

Manually also if I am trying to copy this field from firefox Browser I am unable to do so. But Manually when I am trying to copy the same field through Internet Explorer than I am able to do so.

I have tried both implicit and explicit wait also but timeout exception is raised in that case. Following is the code to fetch this particular field-

```
community_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='BNAZZZWUUGKEZQXF44ZDZMNEC5W1SZZZ__0___OLD']")
    community_name = community_name.get_attribute("value")
    print(community_name)
#If I am applying wait here than timeout exception is raised
```

Following is the HTML code of this particular field-

```
<INPUT  TYPE='hidden' NAME='BNAZZZWUUGKEZQXF44ZDZMNEC5W1SZZZ__0___OLD' ID='BNAZZZWUUGKEZQXF44ZDZMNEC5W1SZZZ__0___OLD' VALUE="bhpb-ean"><input id='BNAZZZWUUGKEZQXF44ZDZMNEC5W1SZZZ__0___OLD_text' name='BNAZZZWUUGKEZQXF44ZDZMNEC5W1SZZZ__0___OLD_text' readonly='' disabled='' value='bhpb-ean'/></td>
```

I have to copy bhpb-ean value from web-browser
I think this can be problem related to Firefox web-browser.There are some other fields also where similar type of issue is raised for getting the value.I have to use Mozilla web-browser only.

Hope I am clear. Can you help me to solve my problem?
Thanks in Advance
**EDIT: I have used correct syntax of xpath in my program but my mistake forget to write // in my question in the syntax of my xpath. Hence I do not get solution of my problem. Can anybody help me.**

Comment: I may be wrong, I don't think you can locate an element with type attribute value "hidden". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden

Comment: @Satish but we are able to copy in Internet Explorer. May be in Mozilla this is not possible.

Comment: My bad then. Is this an app that can be accessed? If so give the URL and somebody here will take a stab at it.

Comment: Please also add the actions before this field is visible. It looks like this field is populated dynamically after the page is loaded which can result in the error you are seeing.

Comment: Is this element in an iframe?

Comment: @BryanOakley no this element is not in iframe

Comment: @Jortega can you please elaborate it?

Comment: @Vishav Gupta it would help me to see the steps in your test that come before the par that causes the error.

Answer (score 2):

To look at your code trail The `xpath` syntax you have provided is wrong.Change the `xpath` syntax and check.

```
community_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='BNAZZZWUUGKEZQXF44ZDZMNEC5W1SZZZ__0___OLD']")
community_name = community_name.get_attribute("value")
print(community_name)
```

Comment: Sorry not to mention // in the beginning of xpath in my question above . But I have mentioned correct syntax of xpath in my program but it didn't solve my problem. Hence I have already used above code and it is not answer to my question

Comment: if I use wrong syntax of xpath than my program will show exception of invalid syntax rather than NoSuchElementFound. This may be problem related to some Firefox element and I want solution of that problem.

Comment: Check if there any iframe present above the element in your Dom tree. Also check Firefox driver and Firefox browser version both are compatible?

Comment: I have checked there is no iframe present and firefox driver and firefox browser version both are compatible

Comment: Well have provided enough wait either explicit or implicit to element visible.

Comment: I have tried to provide maximum wait as possible but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: but this is url of organisation for whom I have to automate the task.This url works in organisation's own network and requires authentication. So sorry that url will not work outside the organisation network

Comment: I think this may be problem related to firefox or some html element